# R / creating a symmetric matrix out of the vector of the lower triangle elements

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I was provided some data to work with in R in vector form. The elements of this vector of size n(n+1)/2 should be rearranged in a symmetric matrix.
Example:

```
n<-4
x<-seq(from=1,to=n*(n+1)/2)
```

What is a nice way to obtain

```
mat<- 1 2 3 4
      2 5 6 7
      3 6 8 9  
      4 7 9 10
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `lower.tri`

```
 m1 <- matrix(, n, n)
 m1[lower.tri(m1, diag=TRUE)] <- x
 m2 <- t(m1)
 m2[lower.tri(m2, diag=TRUE)] <- x
```

Or instead of doing the last two steps

```
 pmax(m1, t(m1), na.rm=TRUE)
 #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]    1    2    3    4
 #[2,]    2    5    6    7
 #[3,]    3    6    8    9
 #[4,]    4    7    9   10
```